# Is there a way to split an array type in SQL (e.g. split function in python)?

Tags: sql, arrays, redash

Hi all I am trying to run an analyses on a table with a column that is an array on redash. I am trying to split the array so that I only grab the second element and create a new column.

When I run the desc function to describe the column I get the following datatype:

`array(row(term varchar, originalvalue varchar, updatedvalue varchar, nestedvalues array(row(term varchar, originalvalue varchar, updatedvalue varchar))))`

For instance here is an example table:

| pkid | datarray |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | [["Metadata",null,null,[["jobClassification","","STUDENT"], ["SubClassification","","Junior"],["Name","",""],["studentDateIndicator","","true"],["isDocumentAcceptable","","true"],["notAcceptableReason","",""], ["schoolName","","University of StackOverflow"],["isSchoolNameSelected","","false"],["assignedSystem","","Empathetic"],["studentDocumentDateType","","Issuance Date"],["studentDocumentDate","","04/12/2023"]]]] |

I want to use a SELECT statement to create a new column based of the `SubClassification` value (in this case `Junior`)

I tried using case statements to create a new column such as below

```
CASE WHEN datarray = '%Junior%' THEN 'Junior'
ELSE 'Other'
END AS ClassClassification
```

I got an error saying the problem was that it was an array type. Does anyone know a work around?